# Как в PhantomJS искать селекторы?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Экспериментирую c Selenium.

Например, если создать объект

```
ChromeDriver chrom = new ChromeDriver();
```

все работает, а тот же вариант с PhantomJS не проходит (ниже) - выбрасывает исключение на phantomjs.FindElement(). Что тут сделать?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for UnitTest2
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest3
    {
        PhantomJSDriver phantomjs;

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod3()
        {
            phantomjs = new PhantomJSDriver();
            phantomjs.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
            phantomjs.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("AutoQA.org");
            phantomjs.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)this.phantomjs).GetScreenshot();
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\image_" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")).ToString() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        }

        // разрушение объекта драйвера после окончание теста.
        [TestCleanup]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            phantomjs.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что за исключение?

Comment: An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Additional information: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'lst-ib'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"31","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:9483"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"lst-ib\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"

Comment: /element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c2033b40-d515-11e6-ba5b-39ea095bef93/element"}}

Comment: добавьте в вопрос, без форматирования невозможно читать

Comment: Почему-то в разные браузеры гугл отдает по-разному. В данном случае фантом получает класс class="lst tiah"